# Python - Looping over a DICT and getting a TraceBack Error

Tags: python

I have created a DICT with BeautifulSoup with a length of 42.  I am trying to extract the text from the  tag and I know that some at the end are blank.  When I enter player[42].text it returns a blank from REPL, but when I call it in a loop I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/Brad/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 997, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0
```

Code:

```
for player in players:
    name = player[0].text.strip()
    print(name)
```

I have looked all over Google and Stackoverflow and found a few If statements to try, but still not luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop iterates over the items in `players` assigning to `player` each item in turn. When trying to index with `player[0]` BeautifulSoup treats it as an attribute lookup using the attribute name `0`. There is no attribute named `0` in the player tag so the lookup fails and `KeyError` is raised.

You should loop like this:

```
for player in players:
    name = player.text.strip()
    print(name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail in the explanation.  Really helps my understanding when I see it explained a couple different ways.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the index. `player` is already a singular object, so you can do:

```
name = player.text.strip() 
print(name)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked perfectly.  Appreciate the help.